# Why does take nodejs so much more virtual memory in OS in comparison to the needed memory of the script?

Tags: node.js, linux, virtual-memory

I'm running a 5k loc express application with a lot of additional dependencies including express. The application says it takes about 60 MB RAM RSS. But when looking at the actual RAM usage on my linux machine `top` tells me it uses ~1200 MB VIRT memory while taking ~60 MB RES (RSS) memory only.

I then wrote a simple `test.js` script to isolate the case:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(process.memoryUsage()));
} , 1000);
```

And started it using: `node test.js`

It tells me it uses around 30 MB RAM:

```
{"rss":30097408,"heapTotal":6537216,"heapUsed":3829224,"external":8272}
```

Looking at the memory in `top` command again, it shows me 30 MB RES, but around 470 MB VIRT usage.

```
PID  USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
8498 ted       20   0  485948  29928  23540 S   0,3  0,8   0:00.44 node
```

NodeJS doesn't seem lightweight this way.

The hoster of my NodeJS application (not the test app) grants me about 600 MB memory permanently for the application but kills my node process after some seconds due to high memory usage. The high virtual memory usage (the mentioned 1200/3800 MB) is taken as a trigger. So my questions are:

**Why is the virtual memory usage for the application so high compared to the actual needed memory? What is the memory taken for?**

**Can I limit the virtual memory for NodeJS anyhow (is it used at all?)?**

Comment: Does your hoster kill the application based on virtual memory usage? Maybe you should explain to them that virtual memory in itself is basically free and limitless, does not correspond to RAM usage, and that they should be looking at rss instead.

Comment: That thought hit me after writing this question, too. Since I never understood that virtual memory thing completely I first wanted to gather some knowledge about it. My previous conclusion was that I just understood it wrong when they wrote that they indeed use the virtual memory as a trigger. Since `Memory overcommitment` and `swap memory` are disabled they say this is the value to use. I can't bring this together with what you have said, too, though.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense. If you mmap a 1GB file, virtual memory usage increases by 1GB but it's backed by disk instead of RAM.

Comment: It's backed by disk only if you have a swap partition. They don't.

Comment: Non-private memory mapped files are always backed by disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issues especially in pods that are in Azure clusters. Their RSS goes up way higher than local machines. **We are basically slowing down (streams, buffers) some queries to give Node Garbage Collection a chance to catch up**. This so far is the only thing that worked, and decreased memory use by 8x (spikes decreased by 3x).

Lots of event listeners can open up too many functions simultaneously, or just dont give Node time to GC.

GC on Node is usually, good, but it has issues, especially during very high load like initialization.